# Missing out http: for images

Tags: html

I see quite a lot of CDNs now and other libraries which show the link as `//blahblah.com/blah` - basically missing out the `http:`

I would assume this then takes the lead from the page as to whether secure (`https:`) or not (`http:`) is put in front of the link.

Are there drawbacks to this and does it apply to images?

I've searched but not sure what to actually type to ask the question so struggling a little bit. As I am here with tags!

Comment: @Quentin I think I agree to be honest, but would recommend leaving it in as it's title is much more laymans terms. Answered it for me so many thanks!

Comment: You can edit the title of the other question if you want. That one should stay and this one should be duplicate simply because of the other question having many answers that would have to be moved here.

Comment: @Takendarkk Agreed, will edit now